# How to resolve "You must install .NET Desktop Runtime to run this application (6.0.16 x64)"?

Tags: technical-issues, linux, wine, lord-of-the-rings-bfme

I'm trying to run the Lord of the Rings - Battle for Middle Earth "[All in One Launcher](https://www.moddb.com/mods/battle-for-middle-earth-patch-222/downloads/patch-222)" on Linux via Wine 8.11. When I run it, I get the following error prompt:

[image: PatchLauncherBFME.exe You must install .NET Desktop Runtime to run this application. Architecture: x64 App host version: 6.0.16 Would you like to download it now? Learn about runtime installation: https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed]

When I run `dotnet --list-sdks` on my Arch Linux host, it says I have both `7.0.7` and `6.0.19` installed.

I've tried installing `dotnet6` and `dotnetdesktop6` (it installed version `6.0.16`) via Winetricks, as well the Windows versions (both x86 and x64) of .NET Desktop Runtime `6.0.19` from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0 then running them with Wine, but the same issue occurs.

How can I get past this issue?

Answer (score 7):

You need both .NET Desktop Runtime, and `hostfxr.dll`

These steps result in a stackoverflow error on the particular BFME Launcher, but they get past the initial .NET Desktop Runtime screen:

- `winetricks dotnetdesktop6`
- Go to https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0
- Download the Windows "Hosting Bundle" (under ASP.NET Core Runtime)
- Run it with Wine (you will now have `hostfxr.dll`, but it won't be in your path)
- Go back to the folder with `PatchLauncherBFME.exe`
- Run `DOTNET_ROOT="~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/dotnet/host/fxr/6.0.19/hostfxr.dll" wine PatchLauncherBFME.exe`

In the last command, I have version `6.0.19` installed, but use whatever you got in the download link

Answer (score 1):

Another answer is to just use `wine-ge-proton` rather than regular `wine`. It doesn't have this issue and gets past the stackoverflow error on the 2.22 Launcher.

One of the easiest ways to get `wine-ge-proton` is to install it as a Runner in the Preferences of [Bottles](https://usebottles.com/), but it can also be found in the GloriousEggroll's repository: https://github.com/GloriousEggroll/wine-ge-custom